# synchronize access to python object

Tags: python, synchronization

I am looking for a general and simple way to synchronize the methods of a python class that does not use asynchronous calls by itself.
Some possibilities come to my mind:
First, the use of decorators on all methods of the class itself: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577105-synchronization-decorator-for-class-methods/.
But I do not wish to change the class, so secondly, the use of a wrapper or a subclass synchronizing access to all subclass/core methods.
I thought maybe, there is a generic way to synchronize access to a python object so that you do not accidentally miss a method from a superclass in the hierarchy (especially if it is changed later on).
So, thirdly, you can probably use a generic proxy similar to: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/366254-generic-proxy-object-with-beforeafter-method-hooks/
and use reentrant locks for each access.
I would prefer the third option. It just bugs me that I did not find a recipe for this. Is there something off with this solution or is there a better one?

**EDIT2:**
The last option looks like the following snippet and was tested with codetidy.com/5911/ .
The test is not a prove that it works, just a light indication. Since this is not my everyday coding, it would help if someone more experienced could check to see if there are any bugs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import types
from pprint import pformat
from threading import RLock

class SynchronizeMethodWrapper:
    """
    Wrapper object for a method to be called.
    """
    def __init__( self, obj, func, name, rlock ):
        self.obj, self.func, self.name = obj, func, name
        self.rlock = rlock
        assert obj is not None
        assert func is not None
        assert name is not None

    def __call__( self, *args, **kwds ):
        """
        This method gets called before a method is called to sync access to the core object.
        """
        with self.rlock:
            rval = self.func(*args, **kwds)
            return rval


class SynchronizeProxy(object):
    """
    Proxy object that synchronizes access to a core object methods and attributes that don't start with _.
    """
    def __init__( self, core ):
        self._obj = core
        self.rlock = RLock()

    def __getattribute__( self, name ):
        """
        Return a proxy wrapper object if this is a method call.
        """
        if name.startswith('_'):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        else:
            att = getattr(self._obj, name)
            if type(att) is types.MethodType:
                return SynchronizeMethodWrapper(self, att, name, object.__getattribute__(self, "rlock"))
            else:
                return att

    def __setitem__( self, key, value ):
        """
        Delegate [] syntax.
        """
        name = '__setitem__'
        with self.rlock:
            att = getattr(self._obj, name)
            pmeth = SynchronizeMethodWrapper(self, att, name, self.rlock)
            pmeth(key, value)
```

**EDIT3:** I went with the SynchronizeProxy, and it seems to work so far. Since this solution comes closest to what I need, I will select my answer as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with the SynchronizeProxy, and it seems to work so far. Since this solution comes closest to what I need, I will select my answer as a solution. If I experience any problems, I will update this answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import types
from pprint import pformat
from threading import RLock

class SynchronizeMethodWrapper:
    """
    Wrapper object for a method to be called.
    """
    def __init__( self, obj, func, name, rlock ):
        self.obj, self.func, self.name = obj, func, name
        self.rlock = rlock
        assert obj is not None
        assert func is not None
        assert name is not None

    def __call__( self, *args, **kwds ):
        """
        This method gets called before a method is called to sync access to the core object.
        """
        with self.rlock:
            rval = self.func(*args, **kwds)
            return rval


class SynchronizeProxy(object):
    """
    Proxy object that synchronizes access to a core object methods and attributes that don't start with _.
    """
    def __init__( self, core ):
        self._obj = core
        self.rlock = RLock()

    def __getattribute__( self, name ):
        """
        Return a proxy wrapper object if this is a method call.
        """
        if name.startswith('_'):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        else:
            att = getattr(self._obj, name)
            if type(att) is types.MethodType:
                return SynchronizeMethodWrapper(self, att, name, object.__getattribute__(self, "rlock"))
            else:
                return att

    def __setitem__( self, key, value ):
        """
        Delegate [] syntax.
        """
        name = '__setitem__'
        with self.rlock:
            att = getattr(self._obj, name)
            pmeth = SynchronizeMethodWrapper(self, att, name, self.rlock)
            pmeth(key, value)
```

Comment: It's been a very long time, but an update would still be great

Comment: @Magnus The solution worked for me at the time, and I did not see a better, or more simple alternative. Nowadays, with more experience working in a team, I would try to put more effort into finding a less elegant / more brute solution covering my need. The trade-off is to have a solution that is a bit ugly, but has the advantage of being accessible to co-workers, future employees (and my future self) when it comes to understanding/reviewing/debugging/changing the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to, you can use the black magic of python metaclasses to dynamically add a decorator to each method of the class at class creation time. The following is a quick example of how you might do this. It creates a generic synchronizer metaclass, which you then subclass to create synchronizers for each specific class. Finally you subclass the original class that you want to synchronize and apply the synchronizer metaclass to it. Note I'm using python 3 metaclass syntax.

```
from threading import RLock

#
# Generic synchronizer
#
class SynchroMeta(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(SynchroMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
        dct['__lock__'] = RLock()

        def sync_decorator(f):
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                with dct['__lock__']:
                    print("Synchronized call")
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
            return inner

        for b in bases:
            if b.__name__ == cls.sync_object_name:
                for name, obj in b.__dict__.items():
                    # Synchronize any callables, but avoid special functions
                    if hasattr(obj, '__call__') and not name.startswith('__'):
                        print("Decorating: ", name)
                        setattr(b, name, sync_decorator(obj))

#
# Class you want to synchronize
#
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.value = v

    def print_value(self):
        print("MyClass.value: ", self.value)

#
# Specific synchronizer for "MyClass" type
#
class MyClassSynchro(SynchroMeta):
    sync_object_name = "MyClass"


#
# Wrapper that uses the specific synchronizer metaclass
#
class MyClassWrapper(MyClass, metaclass=MyClassSynchro):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = MyClassWrapper('hello')
    w.print_value()
```

Comment: If SynchroMeta is a metaclass, as far as I understand metaclasses, there is only one "instance" of it. Therefore only one lock, which would also lock independent instances of MyClass. This is ok, but as far as I can see not better than my approach, especially with many objects of MyClass.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be a reentrant lock, as some methods may call another method of the same class and hence deadlock?

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I'll update. Also for your first comment. There should be a way to add a per instance lock. I think I'd need to also override the `__call__` method of the metaclass and add a lock to each created instance. FYI, I'm no guru on metaclasses, I know just enough to be dangerous =).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a queue to proxy the calls to that class:

http://pymotw.com/2/Queue/

Update:

Actually now that I think about it a queue might not be the best solution because you'd probably have to adapt the class at least a little bit to work with the queue. If you wan't to use locks you could take a look at threading.Lock() here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: Can you elaborate how to proxy calls to a class with a queue and how it is better than the suggested solutions?

Comment: I've adapted my answer a little bit. Hope it helps.