# Python asyncio: synchronize all access to a shared object

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a class which processes a buch of work elements asynchronously (mainly due to overlapping HTTP connection requests) using `asyncio`. A very simplified example to demonstrate the structure of my code:

```py
class Work:
    ...

    def worker(self, item):
        # do some work on item...
        return

    def queue(self):
        # generate the work items...
        yield from range(100)

    async def run(self):
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            tasks = [
                loop.run_in_executor(executor, self.worker, item)
                for item in self.queue()
            ]
            for result in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
                pass

work = Work()
asyncio.run(work.run())
```

In practice, the workers need to access a shared container-like object and call its methods which are not `async`-safe. For example, let's say the `worker` method calls a function defined like this:

```py
def func(shared_obj, value):
    for node in shared_obj.filter(value):
        shared_obj.remove(node)
```

However, calling `func` from a worker might affect the other asynchronous workers in this or any other function involving the shared object. I know that I need to use some [synchronization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html), such as a global lock, but I don't find its usage easy:

- `asyncio.Lock` can be used only in `async` functions, so I would have to mark all such function definitions as `async`
- I would also have to `await` all calls of these functions
- `await` is also usable only in `async` functions, so eventually all functions between `worker` and `func` would be `async`
- if the `worker` was `async`, it would not be possible to pass it to `loop.run_in_executor` (it does not `await`)

Furthermore, some of the functions where I would have to add `async` may be generic in the sense that they should be callable from asynchronous as well as "normal" context.

I'm probably missing something serious in the whole concept. With the `threading` module, I would just create a lock and work with it in a couple of places, without having to further annotate the functions. Also, there is a nice solution to [wrap the shared object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042051/synchronize-access-to-python-object) such that all access is transparently guarded by a lock. I'm wondering if something similar is possible with `asyncio`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm probably missing something serious in the whole concept. With the threading module, I would just create a lock...

What you are missing is that you're not really using `asyncio` at all. `run_in_executor` serves to integrate CPU-bound or legacy sync code into an asyncio application. It works by submitting the function it to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and returning an awaitable handle which gets resolved once the function completes. This is "async" in the sense of running in the background, but not in the sense that is central to asyncio. An asyncio program is composed of non-blocking pieces that use async/await to suspend execution when data is unavailable and rely on the event loop to efficiently wait for multiple events at once and resume appropriate async functions.

In other words, as long as you rely on `run_in_executor`, you *are* just using `threading` (more precisely `concurrent.futures` with a threading executor). You can use a `threading.Lock` to synchronize between functions, and things will work exactly as if you used `threading` in the first place.

To get the benefits of asyncio such as scaling to a large number of concurrent tasks or reliable cancellation, you should design your program as async (or mostly async) from the ground up. Then you'll be able to modify shared data atomically simply by doing it between two awaits, or use `asyncio.Lock` for synchronized modification across awaits.